# Can Eclipse ignore .cvsignore files when synchronizing with a CVS repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, cvs

I am working with a team environment with a heterogeneous blend of IDE's among different developers.  Some use Eclipse, others NetBeans, others IntelliJ, etc.  The code projects are all structured around Maven... so nobody cares which IDE you use as long as it can play with Maven.

To that end, we're not supposed to commit any IDE-specific files (e.g. ".project", ".classpath") to the CVS repository.  I believe that this second part may be overkill... but we're *also* not supposed to commit our ".cvsignore" files, which contain filters for our individual individual IDE-specific files.

It's a bit of a hassle dodging around my ".cvsignore" files every time I sync with the repository.  Is there a way that I can prevent Eclipse from displaying those files in the "Team Synchronizing" perspective?

Comment: My first thought was to simply add the string ".cvsignore" as one of the filters in ".cvsignore"!  However, Eclipse ignores this self-reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add patterns to *Window -> Preferences -> Team -> CVS -> Ignored Resources*. This should cause Eclipse Team CVS to ignore the file when commiting.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I've never noticed that functionality before.  For my purposes, this makes more sense than using ".cvsignore" files at all in the first place!

Comment: Well, .cvsignore is certainly useful in other instances. In fact, if you had team members developing in something like EditPlus or Textmate, I'd advocate maintaining a basic .cvsignore and having it checked-in to the project so that developers using cvs from the command-line (or other external tools) don't check-in .class files and the like. As it is, your project manager is simply assuming that all IDEs have sensible ignore policies already in place. That may or may not be a valid assumption.

Comment: @yock: Seems there *is* a .cvsignore file, they just don't want individual developers messing with it. I can understand such a policy.