# Eclipse does not respect .cvsignore

Tags: eclipse, cvs

In my project there is a symlink to a folder from another project.
The name of this folder is in .cvsignore

But this folder (symlink) contains cvs metadata (CVS folders) from the other project.

The cvs command has no problem with this and ignores the folder.

But eclipse wants to synchronize it.

The question is, can ecplise ignore a folder at synchronize time, or how to make eclipse respect .cvsignore files?

the folder (symlink) name is shared and in my .cvsignore contains a line with it's name

We use the symlink trick to share sources between our software and its plugins which are built separately (separate autotools projects).

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: 3.7.0 CDT and also on previous version 3.5.2 CDT

Comment: does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402425/can-eclipse-ignore-cvsignore-files-when-synchronizing-with-a-cvs-repository

Comment: Unfortunatly no, it does not work with folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is an explicitly shared folder overriding the .cvsignore entry.

You can find the exact details as explained by the previous Eclipse CVS component lead within [bug 169710](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=169710). This bug is marked as a duplicate of another defect which is still open, meaning this is a known issue.

As Michael pointed out, your choice is to use an Eclipse link for development:

- Add new folder to Eclipse project
- Select **Advanced** > **Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)**
- Select the workspace variable (i.e. **WORKSPACE_LOC**) and point to the other project on your workspace (i.e. WORKSPACE_LOC/other_project/foo)

This will get you a linked resource that developers don't have to worry about mistakenly checking-in. For your automated builds you'll need an extra post-checkout step where you create the symlink.

This is not ideal but it's a sensible alternative, short of fixing the Eclipse issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll see what I will do, because our team policy is to not commit IDE files. when someone check out one of our projects the only things needed are autotools & gcc, so the developper can use eclispe, netbeans, vi, whatever.

Comment: Ah yes, the issue becomes a little more complicated if you haven't standardized on an IDE. If you find a creative way around that issue don't forget to post it back here!